# How to add plug-in tabs at the right place for me?

Tags: c#, plugins, tfs, tfs-2015

I'm trying to write a plugin for TFS **2015** (its important). I read a couple of manuals. the examples all turns out simply, but it is more difficult with a real plugin. my problem: i want to add 2 action buttons with my functionality, like this:
https://gyazo.com/344001e344826792be76d5faeb64c8fb

but in https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-workitem-extension#addmenuaction I could not find a solution of my problem.

how can i add 2 action buttons to my tfs in right place?

Comment: To know the right place of the extension, you could check out all of the targetable hub groups in this link: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/targets/overview#targetable-hub-groups

Comment: thx, but i saw this examples and they dont have any solutions of my problem.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, didn't noticed the 1st and 2nd button. Have updated my reply in below answer. Please kindly review it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To add the 1st button,** it's not support for now. You cannot create a hub at this level (outside of a project). The highest you can go is a [hub group](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-hub-group). As mentioned above, here is a list of all the currently [supported extension points.](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/targets/overview)

**To add the 2nd button,** this is not belongs extensions.You just need to customize the work item form.

The following illustration highlights the most common elements on work item forms. You can customize all of them except the title area and form controls.

[image]

- Add new tabs or columns, or move groups of fields from one tab to
  another. See [Design the work item form.](http://Add%20new%20tabs%20or%20columns,%20or%20move%20groups%20of%20fields%20from%20one%20tab%20to%20another.%20See%20Design%20the%20work%20item%20form.)

More details please refer this tutorial: [Customize the work item form](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/add-modify-wit#customize-the-work-item-form)